# Show that $\bar E = E \cup E'$

Tags: real-analysis

A point x is called an accumulation point of a set E provided it is a point of closure of $E= {x}.$ Show that the set $E'$ of accumulation points of $E$ is a close set. 
Proof: we now prove part one.

To show that $E'$ is closed, we have to show that the compliment is open.

Let's pick an $x \in(E')^{c}$, then the exist an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the interval $(x- \epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$ contains no point of $E'$ except possibly the point $x$ itself. Let $y \in (x- \epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$. Since $(x- \epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$ is open we can always find a $\delta > 0$ such that we have an interval $(y- \delta, y+ \delta)$. so that $(y- \delta, y+ \delta) \subset (x- \epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$. this means every point in the interval around x is an interior point of $(E')^{c}$ so $(E')^{c}$ is open. therefor $E'$ is closed.

I feel like this reasoning is ok but i am having difficulty with the second part.. any idea that would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Adding some paragraph breaks will make your post much more readable.

Comment: i don't really know how to do that. i tried

Comment: Try hitting 'Enter' or 'Return' on the keyboard...

Comment: yeah when i do that it does not change anything

Comment: You must hit the key twice (you need a blank line separating the text in the edit window).

Comment: thanks just finish the editing i appreciate the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious that $E‎‎‎\subseteq‎ \bar E$ and $E'‎‎‎ \subseteq‎ \bar E$, so $E \cup E'\subseteq \bar E$. To show the reverse containment, suppose $x\in \bar E$ and $x \not\in E$. Then by definition $B_{\delta}(x)\cap E$ is nonempty, so $x \in E'$.

Comment: I was thinking proving that $\bar E \subset E' \cup E$ and $E' \cup E \subset \bar E$

Comment: sorry that is exactly what i was thinking my apologies for the previous coment

Comment: Its ok dear, :)